# Implementation of FITC approximation for Gaussian Processes

Tags: gaussian-process

I'm attempting to use Gaussian processes for classification. When using a large number of observations, sparse approaches are used to deal with the scalability issue of O(N^3). Sparse approaches typically reduce the computation cost to O(N*M^2).

Currently I'm trying to implement the code provided in the pyGPs python package: https://github.com/marionmari/pyGPs. However I'm finding the computation cost is not being reduced.

In the following example I use an built sklearn function to generate some data to implement classification. X and y correspond to the features and class labels restively. There are 10000 observations and the features have dimension 10. I then split the data into train and test data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import pyGPs
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
%matplotlib inline  

n_generate = 10000
n_feature = 10
X, y = make_classification(n_generate, n_feature)
for i in range(n_generate):
    if y[i] == 0:
        y[i] = -1

X_train = X[0:int(n_generate/2.0),]
y_train = y[0:int(n_generate/2.0)]
X_test = X[int(n_generate/2 + 1):n_generate]
y_test =    y[int(n_generate/2 + 1):n_generate]
```

I try to use the pyGPs package to apply Gaussian processes to this process as follows:

```
 model = pyGPs.GPC_FITC() 
 model.setData(X_train, y_train)
 model.optimize()
 model.predict(X_test)
```

However the computation time is taking too long. Has anyone experience using this package to speed up computations?

Comment: This seems to be more about the Python code than the ML aspects. This Q belongs on [SO] rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of inducing points is $5$ along each input dimension by default. So you have $5^{10} \approx 10^7$ inducing points, so you have to do inference with sample size $10^7$ - so no speedup.

You can speed up your inference in two ways:

- specify different number of inducing points along each dimension. If you use $2$ instead of $5$ you will get $2^{10} = 1024$ points. In this case use

`model.setData(X_train, y_train, value_per_axis=2)`

- set inducing points manually. For example, select $100$ or $1000$ points from your initial sample at random. In this case instead of `model.setData` use

`model.setPrior(inducing_points=None)`

Answer (score 0):

Now I introduce my own inducing points as follows:

```
n_inducing_points = 10
Inducing_points = np.zeros((n_inducing_points, n_feature))
for i in range(n_feature):
Inducing_points[:,i] = np.linspace(min(X_train[:, i]), max(X_train[:,    i]), n_inducing_points)
```

This is a matrix of 10 x n_feature (10 inducing points) and I use the code:

```
model = pyGPs.GPC_FITC()
model.setData(X_train, y_train)
model.setPrior(inducing_points = Inducing_points)
model.optimize()
```

This does not compute in a reasonable time at all. Compare this to :

```
model = pyGPs.GPC_FITC()
axis_induce_points = 2
model.setData(X_train, y_train, value_per_axis = axis_induce_points )
model.optimize()
```

The second code implements fast where I now have 2^10 inducing points.

Can you explain where I'm going wrong. The first should have 10 and doens't run, but the second runs with 1000 inducing points. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, look through manual http://www-ai.cs.uni-dortmund.de/weblab/static/api_docs/pyGPs/_downloads/pyGPs_API.pdf. I have no idea why this thing happens. May be switch setData and setPrior strings?